# jquery submit ajaxSubmit() not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-forms-plugin

I am having issue setting up a file upload element with cakePHP to be used inside a form and ajaxSubmit() function does not send a ajax request.. my code as follows any ideas appreciated

also in another element I was very successfully with the uploading file with .ajaxForm() method.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('#frmFileForm1').ajaxForm({
                url: 'http://up.dev/admin/pages/file',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                success: function() {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                    reloadfilemanager();
                }
            });

                var options = {
                    url: 'http://up.dev/admin/pages/file',
                    iframe: true,
                    type: 'post',
                    target: '#status',
                    data: 'submitBtn'
                    }


             $('button').click(function() {
                $('#frmFileForm1').ajaxSubmit(options);
               alert("AA");
             });


        });

    </script>
<div>
        <?php

//<!-- form for uploading file -->

        echo $this->Form->button('Upload File', array( 'name' => 'submitBtn', 'class' => 'btn_submit', 'style' => 'margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;', 'type' => 'submit'));
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your selector:

```
$('button').click(function() {
```

change to this:

```
$('.btn_submit').click(function() {
```

---

Because your button type is `type="submit"` and your selector is targeting the `type="button"` which is not available there, it seems to me.

---

#### Update:

Instead of `click` of button try with `submit` event:

```
var options = {
           url: 'http://up.dev/admin/pages/file',
           iframe: true,
           type: 'post',
           target: '#status',
           data: 'submitBtn'
         }; //<----add ; here not that much issue with this though


$('#frmFileForm1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    alert("AA");
});
```

Comment: I tried using $('.btn_submit').click(function() { still having does not trigger ajaxSubmit() to my understanding problum is not with button trigger cus the alert works.. after .ajaxSubmit();

Comment: @Prasad see the upadates.

Comment: Hai Jai thks for the update unfortunately no luck .. may because the form is within another form ..

Comment: @prasad yes this should be the case.